# Using JSX with VueJS, why are my spread operator props assigned to $vnode.data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My component:

`const fieldProps = { name: 'phone', value: '' }`

`<InputField {...fieldProps} />`

Those props are found in `this.$vnode.data` instead of `this.$props`.

When I pass props separately, props are found in `this.$props`.

i.e.: `<InputField name={'phone'} value="" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you missed adding the `props` key inside `InputField` component, the props will be only available in `$vnode` and not in `$props`.

The key `props` is required inside `fieldProps` to make it work. It’s mentioned in the code snippet [here](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx/issues/51).

So `fieldProps` should look like this:

```
const fieldProps = {
    props: { name: 'phone', value: '' }
}
```

Please have a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y9npz8614) inside `Hello` component and comment/uncomment the `props` property to see the difference.